# how to replace with default value when querying a JSONB column with a key that is not present in a particular row giving empty result

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, subquery

I have a table that has a **jsonb** column as 'result' which has an array of objects.

Looks like this for every row:

```
[{"grade": "A", "subject": "MATH"}, {"grade": "B", "subject": "PHY"}...]
```

When I am querying this way

```
select up.id, jsonb_array_elements(to_jsonb(up.result)) ->>'subject' as result 
from "UserProfile"
```

I get correct result but problem arises when I query for a particular row with an id wherein this result column has an empty array data. Then it neither gives any result nor an error even though I am selecting 'id' in query. not able to put any default value also using **coalesce**

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Use a left join:

```
select up.id, r.element ->>'subject' as result 
from "UserProfile" up
  left join jsonb_array_elements(up.result) as r(element) on true
```